# error: The string representation of a date/time value is out of range

Tags: java, sql, database, date, db2

I'm working on a local java database and I keep having this error while trying to insert a date in my database table

**Error**

> Error code 30000, SQL state 22007: The string representation of a date/time value is out of range

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO
   conference (titre, institut_organisatrice, date_conf, date_limite_soumission, date_limite_inscription, montant, frais_inscrit_pro, frais_inscrit_acadm, frais_inscrit_etud, idpresident) 
VALUES
   (
      'Smart Tunisia', 'ministere de la recherche scientifique', '05/10/2019', '20/09/2019', '20/09/2019', 300, 200, 150, 50, 1
   )
;
```

Comment: You should tag your dbms for better answers. If you use ISO dates you'll probably get rid of this error: `'20191005'` instead of `'05/10/2019'`

Comment: The standard for SQL dates is `yyyy-mm-dd`. In any case, if you are working with JDBC, better use prepared statement and use `setObject` with a `LocalDate` or other applicable object from `java.time`.

Comment: then it shows incorrect syntax

Comment: Is `'05/10/2019'` the 5th of October, or the 10th of May? Much better to use the ISO standard of `'YYYY-MM-DD'` that will work in DB2 regardless of any locale setting

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement                                   // Use a prepared statement for most of your SQL work, to pass objects in your JDBC code. Bonus: Doing so avoids SQL-injection attacks too.
.setObject(                                           // Replace a `?` placeholder in your SQL statement.
    … ,                                               // Specify which `?` placeholder.
    LocalDate.parse(                                  // Use `LocalDate` class for a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.
        "05/10/2019" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" )   // Specify a formatting pattern to match your input string.
    )
)
```

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

For date-time values, use date-time types in SQL (`DATE`) and Java (`LocalDate`). Using appropriate types rather than mere strings makes your code [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code), ensures valid values, and provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

## `PreparedStatement` & placeholders

Change your SQL to use `?` placeholders with a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). As a bonus, you will be eliminating the risk of [SQL-Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Search Stack Overflow for class name [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to learn more. This has been covered many manny times already.

## `LocalDate`

Parse your string inputs as `LocalDate` objects.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ); 
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "05/10/2019" , f ) ;
```

Specify values for the placeholders.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

When retrieving from a `DATE` column in the database.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

## ISO 8601

Tip: Learn to use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when serializing date-time values as text. Use localized formats only for presentation to the user, and not inside your business logic.

Conveniently, the *java.time* classes use standard formats by default when generating and parsing strings.

```
LocalDate.parse( "2019-05-10" )  // May 10, 2019.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

if you date columns are proper date  data type
you should use

```
'2019/10/05'
```

or

```
str_to_date('05/10/2019', '%d/%m/%Y')
```